# Elements of multidimensional List

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a very large 3D List, out of which - for example - the first element reads:

```
In[12]:= A = Zeropi1pEvents[[1]]

Out[12]= {{1, 3, 902, -1, 0.00001322118, 0., 0., 0., 0.8353713, \
-0.1763927, -0.1532843, 0.7950288, 0, 2, 1.097166}, {1, 3, 1, 0, \
0., 0., 0., 0., 0.8863627, -0.02104685, -0.06873666, -0.01801131, 0, \
2, 1.097166}, {1, 3, 1, 0, 0.00001322118, 0.9189929, 0.113536, \
22.09291, 1.09887, 0.02276057, -0.0158158, 0.5717545, 1002001, 2, \
1.097166}, {1, 3, 1, 1, 0.00001322118, 1.622211, 4.360793, \
-7.01601, 0.9692001, 0.01591564, 0.0176974, -0.2428701, 1002001, 2, \
1.097166}}
```

*I now want to get the 9th element of one of these sublists.*

So - for example - I take

```
In[14]:= B = A[[1]]

Out[14]= {1, 3, 902, -1, 0.00001322118, 0., 0., 0., 0.8353713, \
-0.1763927, -0.1532843, 0.7950288, 0, 2, 1.097166}
```

This obviously works as it should. Now I want to get the 9th element of this list *B*.  I do `B[[9]]`and get an error:

```
In[15]:= B[[9]]

During evaluation of In[15]:= Part::partd: Part specification {1, 3, 902, -1, 0.00001322118, 0., 0., 0., 0.8353713, -0.1763927, -0.1532843, 0.7950288, 0, 2, 1.097166}[[9]] is longer than depth of object.

Out[15]= {1, 3, 902, -1, 0.00001322118, 0., 0., 0., 0.8353713, \
-0.1763927, -0.1532843, 0.7950288, 0, 2, 1.097166}[[9]]
```

What is going wrong here? What is the correct way to get the 9th element of one of the sublists of *A*?

Comment: With Zeropi1pEvents[[1,9]] you will get the 9th element of the first list in your list of lists.

Comment: Your code runs without error (Mathematica v12(windows)